# How to get name of operation that fired trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Say I have a TSQL trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Trigger1 ON dbo.Table1
  AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
```

How do I know which one of the above operations (insert, update, or delete) caused the trigger to fire?

Comment: Specifically, see this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10928151/334849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check for the existence of the `inserted` and `deleted` tables.

If only values in `inserted` exist, it was an insert. If only values in `deleted` exist, it was a delete. If both, it was an update.

Comment: Sorry, had to edit for semantics. `inserted` and `deleted` will exist, they just may be empty depending on the action.

Comment: @Aaron I actually didn't realize that, thanks.