# Some issue with logical tables (DELETED, INSERTED) in procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I try use logical tables in procedure but I have error:

> "Invalid object name DELETED"

So first question can I use  logical tables in procedure? 
If yes how can I do this?

This is a code

```
USE Operator
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE generuj ( @nazwaTabeli VARCHAR(20) )
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--
-- Check if this is an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE Action.
-- 
DECLARE @action as char(1);

SET @action = 'I'; -- Set Action to Insert by default.
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED) --Invalid object name DELETED
BEGIN
    SET @action = 
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) -- Invalid object name INSERTED
THEN 'U' -- Set Action to Updated.
            ELSE 'D' -- Set Action to Deleted.       
        END


END



        INSERT INTO TBLLOGI (UZYTKOWNIK,NAZWATABELI,DATAOPERACJI,TYPOPERACJI)
        VALUES (SYSTEM_USER,@nazwaTabeli,SYSDATETIME(),@action)


END
```

I have it from this topic [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741414/insert-update-trigger-how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update) 
I want use this procedure on trigger which looks like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgLogi 
ON TBLABONENCI
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
EXEC generuj  TBLABONENCI
END;
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables are available only in triggers or as part of OUTPUT clause.If your trigger is calling a procedure, you should save them to tables first to use them from inside the procedure.

Comment: *‘…available only in triggers **and** as part of OUTPUT clause’* – I think the *and* there should be an *or*. Otherwise it reads as if both conditions should be satisfied, which is not correct.