# SQL - Cannot print values from 'inserted' table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have heard that the 'inserted' table automatically stores the last inserted record of any table temporarily.I was able to get the values from this inserted table when using triggers but not manually as

```
insert into samantha (id , name) values (11,'has')
select *from inserted
```

I am getting the error message as

```
Invalid object name 'inserted'.
```

Can you please give the reason.Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you are restricted to using them only in triggers. ["You can use these **temporary**, **memory-resident tables** to test the effects of certain data modifications and to set conditions for **DML trigger actions**"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251739/some-issue-with-logical-tables-deleted-inserted-in-procedure its a duplicate

Comment: Show us complete trigger coding to get better solution.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are part of the implementation of SQL Server triggers and OUTPUT clause. Is there a reason why this question is tagged [tag:mysql]?

Comment: Is this about SQL Server or MySQL? Please remove the wrong tag

Comment: @Radu Gheorghiu ....thanks

Comment: @Puneet Chawla....got the answer...thanks man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is inserted table, but it can be only used with `output` clause, with something like this:

```
insert into samantha (id , name) 
output inserted.*
values (11,'has')
```

If you have an identity field and you want the latest value from it, you can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() -function too:

```
insert into samantha (id , name) 
values (11,'has')

select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: This is for SQL Server, it seem you have tagged also MySQL

Answer (score 0):

try use SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() from samantha

Comment: This doesn't really look like a solution for what the OP asked.. how do you get the `name`?

Comment: the OP asked how to get data from last inserted by trigger in updated MySql. From MySql 5.0 until newest, the trigger for get last inserted data is LAST_INSERT_ID(). that trigger is used to get id from last inserted data.

Comment: He is also trying to get the value inserted in the `name` column. How can he do that?