# SQL Trigger inserted deleted table contents on UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I know from ([Insert Update trigger how to determine if insert or update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741414/insert-update-trigger-how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update)) that an UPDATE transaction causes rows in the deleted table

what are the contents of inserted and deleted when updating a single row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Inserted` contains that one row being updated with the new values (**after** the `UPDATE`), while `Deleted` contains that one row being updated with the old values (**before** the `UPDATE`)