# Trigger Update another table After Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have 2 tables `Employee` and `Employee_Backup`

`Employee` has 3 columns

- IDEmployee
- Name
- Status

and `Employee_Backup` also has 3 columns:

- IDEmployee
- Detail
- Status

For every row inserted into or updated in table `Employee`, I want to set the `Status` in table `Employee_Backup` using this criteria

```
WHERE employee_backup.IDEmployee = employee.IDEmployee     (inserted / updated)
```

Comment: Hi there is a clear outline on the TRIGGERS you are looking for here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741414/insert-update-trigger-how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update

Comment: i can't make it automatically, i have try many way in google but no one is works.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that??

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Employee_Insert
ON dbo.Employee
FOR INSERT 
AS
    UPDATE b
    SET Status = 'Inserted'
    FROM dbo.Employee_Backup b
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON b.EmployeeID = i.EmployeeID


CREATE TRIGGER tr_Employee_Update
ON dbo.Employee
FOR UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE b
    SET Status = 'Updated'
    FROM dbo.Employee_Backup b
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON b.EmployeeID = i.EmployeeID
```

You basically need to **join** the `Inserted` pseudo table which contains all rows that have been inserted (or updated) from the base table (`dbo.Employee`) and the `Employee_Backup` table - and then use that result set from the JOIN as the basis for your `UPDATE` statement.

Note: this will **NOT** insert any new rows into `Employee_Backup` when you add new rows to `dbo.Employee` - is that what you want? If not, you'd have to change the `FOR INSERT` trigger a bit ....

Comment: ya, I just need update status field from employee_backup whenever I insert or update data on table Employee.

Comment: if I implement your suggestion, the result is always 'inserted' not Updated. whenever i try to update, it's prohibited. It says 'the data not commited' before I implement your suggestion. it is fine to update