# Insert and delete in one trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

How can I combine the following two triggers, one 'after insert' and the other 'after delete' into one trigger?

```
create trigger TechStaff_update_Studio
on TechStaff after insert
begin
    update Studio
    set employees = employees + 1
    where studioID = Studio.studioID
end

create trigger TechStaff_update_Studio2
on TechStaff after delete
as
begin
    update Studio
    set employees = employees - 1
    where studioID = Studio.studioID
end
```

Comment: Which SQL Server are you targeting? Have you checked this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741414/insert-update-trigger-how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741414/insert-update-trigger-how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update)?

Comment: I use SSMS 2008. Thank you. the link helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, I guess:

```
create trigger TechStaff_update_Studio
on TechStaff after insert, delete
as
begin
    update s set employees = employees
        + (select count(*) from inserted)
        - (select count(*) from deleted)
    from Studio s

end
```

Notice that you must actually count rows rather than assuming one row inserted/deleted per trigger execution (e.g. `delete * from TechStaff` would fire the trigger **once**).

See MSDN on [the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms191300.aspx).

And your where clause was always true (`studioID = studioID`), and therefore not needed. I assume you did mean to update every row of the Studio table (is there only one row?).

*Edit:* Since you say there are multiple `Studio` rows, you will need to be more clever. You have to get the count of deleted and inserted rows by StudioID. The following could probably be simplified, but I lack the time to make it shorter.

```
create trigger TechStaff_update_Studio
on TechStaff after insert, delete
as
begin
    update s set employees = employees + c.Delta
    from Studio s
    join (
        select StudioID, sum(i) as Delta
        from (
            select StudioID, 1 as i from inserted
            union all
            select StudioID, -1 as i from deleted 
        ) counts
        group by StudioID
    ) c on c.StudioID = s.StudioID
end
```

Comment: You may well be right. Still, I won't bother writing code for that until OP confirms.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you very much!
like jpw said, there are many rows in the Studio table.

Comment: @user1670163 In that case, please check my edit. The original one will not give correct counts for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you could handle it in one trigger like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[<TriggerName>]
ON [<SchemaName>].[<TabaleName>] FOR INSERT, DELETE
AS 
........-- Your Code
```

And remember that inside the Trigger, you can use two tables `Deleted` and `Inserted`  that they have the same as structure as your table and they have the rows that was inserted or deleted.

For more information see this link : [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are "tables" you can use to check if data is INSERTED or DELETED (updates are considered as deletes).

Use it on your IF statement:

For checking updates:

```
SELECT * FROM DELETED
```

For checking inserts:

```
SELECT * FROM INSERTED
```

**EDIT:**

This is for SQL Server