# SQLite - Create Trigger for Insert or Update

Tags: sqlite, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

Is this possible to create one trigger for Insert and Update operations in SQLite?
I mean, something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TR_TableName_TriggerName
    ON dbo.TableName
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
        -- DELETE
        PRINT 'DELETE';
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
            -- INSERT
            PRINT 'INSERT';
        ELSE
            -- UPDATE
            PRINT 'UPDATE';
    END
END;
```

It's for MS SQL i think, source: [Insert Update trigger how to determine if insert or update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741414/insert-update-trigger-how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update)

---

Edit:
Is it possible to create also one trigger for more than one table?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, the [syntax graph](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) for `CREATE TRIGGER` clearly shows that only one of `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` can be given.

It also shows that only one table can be given as a table to trigger on.