# populate a table with DML statements which is done on another table using trigger

Tags: plsql, database-trigger

I have 3 tables:

```
data(operation_name,table_name,operation_date,prim_key)
table2(col1,col2,col3,col4)
table3(col1,col2,col3,col4)
```

I need a trigger which will populate data table whenever an operation(insert,update or delete) is done on table2 or table3.

In data table:

operation_name>> name of DML statement(insert, update or delete) done on table1 or table3

table_name>> name of table on which operation is done.

operation_time>> date at which operation is done.

prim_key>> it should automatically display the primary key of the table on which operation is done.

I am very new to pl/sql and trying various things, but none of them are working.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have tried, and what's not working?

Comment: @eaolson i tried from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741414/insert-update-trigger-how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update)

Comment: Again, show what you've done that isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [It's Not Working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking) can get you downvoted because people like to see some code they can fix. Also the link you posted is for Microsoft SQL Server, but you mentioned PL/SQL so it looks like you're using Oracle.