# Tables Update Using EF

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two SQL table (Tbl_FoodPrice , Tbl_RatioContents), Tbl_FoodPrice contains food prices, and Tbl_RatioContents of animal food composition based on the contribution of each substance. I would like to change the price of the material's share in the Tbl_RatioContents when the price of food is changed in Table 1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Probably you want to tag entity-framework and the version of that which is used also.

Comment: Why not use stored procedure to handle your logic in DB?

Answer (score 0):

The **data update trigger** is triggered by an UPDATE operation.
The INSERTED table stores row values after an update.
For example, a trigger that will be triggered when adding and updating data:

```
USE somedb;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER FoodPrice_INSERT_UPDATE
ON Tbl_FoodPrice
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
UPDATE Tbl_FoodPrice
SET Price = Price + Price * 10
WHERE Id = (SELECT Id FROM INSERTED)
```

You will find more examples: [Insert Update trigger how to determine if insert or update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741414/insert-update-trigger-how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update)