# How to create a trigger that will only update a record if old record is different from new in SQL

Tags: sql

Any table example would be appreciated how I would try going about comparing

Create Trigger Customer_Update
ON Customer UPDATE
AS

Comment: "will only update a record if old record is different from new" - How will you see the difference? If the update happens, the row will look as before. If the update doesn't happen, the row will also look like before.

Comment: You've tagged two different DBMS (MySQL and SQL Server). I've remove these tags. Please tag only the DBMS you are using.

Comment: You reference `inserted` and `deleted`. Join the tables and compare as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables in SQL Server. Remember to cater for nultiple rows being updated. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741414/insert-update-trigger-how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update) should help you out.